# Why were my notes deleted when I permanently deleted emails on gmail site

Tags: notes.app

Why were my notes deleted when I permanently deleted my emails from gmail account.  Can I get my notes recovered? My notes on Apple phone were lynced to Mac I am told.? Can you help

Comment: I assume you where syncing notes via your mail account (standard before iCloud sync was introduced in iOS9 and OS X 10.11) and deleted the notes when cleaning your mails on gmail. Can you perhaps recover the deleted mails (from trash)? If not, do you have TimeMachine backups from your Mac that could be used to recover the deleted mails?

Answer (score 1):

If you were syncing your Notes via your Gmail account (and not via iCloud) then Gmail treats them like a plain text email. If you delete your email, then you also deleted the notes.

Restoring from backup is your only bet - either a Time Machine backup or by recovering lost email.

Comment: PS to avoid this in the future, I keep Notes turned OFF for email accounts and ON for iCloud. This separates my Notes from my email accounts.